# put equation to calculate value for new column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column in my table by implementing equation, but there might be 2 possible equations for the new table.

```
(1) frequency = (total x 100) / hour
(2) frequency = (total x 1000000) / km_length
```

the table is similar to this:

```
type   hour  km_length   total 
A       1       -          1
B       -       2          1
```

the calculation for "frequency" table would depend on which columns between hour and km_length that has value.

then, I expect the table will be like this:

```
type    hour     km_length    total   frequency
A        1          -           1      100
B        -           2          1      500000
```

I have tried using np.nan_to_num before but it did not show the expected table I want.

is there anyway I can make it using python? Looking forward to any help
thankyou.

Comment: The missing values, are they actual `-` or `NaN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `np.where` for assigning values based on a condition:

```
df[["hour", "km_length"]] = df[["hour", "km_length"]].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")

df["frequency"] = np.where(
    df["km_length"].isna(), 
    df["total"] * 100 / df["hour"],
    df["total"] * 1_000_000 / df["km_length"]
)

  type  hour  km_length  total  frequency
0    A   1.0        NaN      1      100.0
1    B   NaN        2.0      1   500000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your values numeric then multiply. Because a missing value indicates with method to use and because division with `NaN` results in a `NaN` do both multiplications and use `.fillna` to determine the correct resulting value.

```
df[['hour', 'km_length']] = df[['hour', 'km_length']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

s1 = df['total'].divide(df['hour']).multiply(100)
s2 = df['total'].divide(df['km_length']).multiply(10**6)

df['frequency'] = s1.fillna(s2)
```

---

```
  type  hour  km_length  total  frequency
0    A   1.0        NaN      1      100.0
1    B   NaN        2.0      1   500000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

table = np.array([['hour' , 'km_lenght' ,  'total' , 'frequrncy']] #set the value of frequency as 0

for i in table:
    try:
        i[3] = (i[2]*100)/i[0]
    except:
        i[3] = (i[2]*1000000)/i[1]

print(table)
```

This should print the desired table.